# @Resource and @Autowired returning null with aspect log

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I have the following problem. Log in aspect with the resources of the controller are always null. This is because I put "final" of the controller methods. How I can fix it without removing the "final"?

My code:

Aplication context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    ....

    <cache:annotation-driven /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="logAspect" class="es.xxx.xxx.xxx.aop.LoggingAspect" />

    <!-- Scan de paquetes por anotaciones Spring -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="es.xxx" />
    ....
</beans>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller("documentController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/documentation")
    public class DocumentController {

        @Resource
        private FileService fileService;

        @Resource
        private FooService fooService;

        @Resource
        private MessageSource messageSource;

        @RequestMapping("/foo.html")
        public final String foo(Params...) {
            ...
            //here are null and throw null pointer exception
            fileService.fooMethod();
            fooService.fooMethod();
            messageResource.fooMethod();
            ...

            return view;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Aspect log:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Around("execution(* es.xxx.xxx.xxx.controller.*.*(..))")
    public Object aroundController(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        logger.debug("...");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* es.xxx.xxx.xxx.controller.*.*(..))", returning="retVal")
    public void afterReturningController(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        logger.debug("...");
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* es.xxx.xxx.xxx.controller.*.*(..))", throwing="exception")
    public void afterThrowingController(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        logger.debug("...", exception);
    }

    @Around("execution(* es.xxx.xxx.xxx.service.impl.*.*(..))")
    public Object aroundService(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        logger.debug("...");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* es.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.impl.*.*(..))", returning="retVal")
    public void afterReturningService(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        logger.debug("...");
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* es.xxx.xxx.xxx.service.impl.*.*(..))", throwing="exception")
    public void afterThrowingService(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        logger.debug("...", exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: does your DocumentController has an annotation like Component, Service, Controller or RestController ? If not there is your problem it's not detected as a spring bean by component scaning

Comment: Yes I have them. I had forgotten to put in the post code.

Comment: Please show the code where you're calling `foo`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot "@RequestMapping". It is a method that maps a view.